# Postfix server to receive emails for anyonymous user

Tags: postfix, email-server

I have a postfix server configured with `imap`. Only the recipient with the user account in the system is accepted. For example: `rcpt to: test@localhost` will yield the following error:

```
550 5.1.1 <test@localhost>: Recipient address rejected: User unknown in local recipient table
```

What I want to achieve is setup virtual maps which accepts email to all the users (even if the user doesn't accept in the system) then forward all those emails to a specific user mailbox. Is something like this, possible?

Answer (score 1):

`postfix` is MTA and `imapd` is MTU and they are two completely different systems. Try go over following document, hopefully it will help you understand mail better:

[How email works (MTA, MDA, MUA)](http://en.kioskea.net/contents/116-how-email-works-mta-mda-mua)

but as your goal itself it's possible to archive that using

[How To Configure a Mail Server Using Postfix, Dovecot, MySQL, and SpamAssasin | DigitalOcean](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/articles/how-to-configure-a-mail-server-using-postfix-dovecot-mysql-and-spamassasin)

Comment: I believe this is indeed possible in the postfix. After doing some research, I removed `mydomain` from mydestination so that postfix now accepts all the recipients even if it is not the system level user. To redirect, I think it's possible using virtual map to redirect to one specific user. Thus, one specific user will have all the e-mails of that postfix server.

Comment: Do you think it's a good approach?